# Find the derivative of an integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Find the derivative of the following integral

$$
F(x)=\int_x^{x^2}e^{t^7}dt 
$$

Find F′(x) given F(x).

Normally I would show my attempt in working out the problem: however, I don't even know where to start with this question. I am thrown of by the variables acting as the lower and upper boundaries of the integral.

Comment: Wouldn't the result of the integral be in the form $F(a)-F(b)$ for endpoints $a,b$?  Perhaps there is a chain rule that could apply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$U(t) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{t^7}dt$$
$$F(x) = U(x^2) - U(x)$$
$$F'(x) = (2x)U'(x^2) - (1)U'(x) = 2xU'(x^2) - U'(x)$$
Of course, $U'(t) = e^{t^7}$ so
$$F'(x) = 2xe^{x^{14}}-e^{x^7}$$

Comment: Did you get 2x from the derivative of $x^2$? And if so, is there suppose to be a hidden 1 in $e^{x^7}$ which comes from differentiating x?

Comment: Yes and yes. Updated to be more clear, thanks.